# How to resolve "memory cannot be written" for py2exe?

Tags: python, memory, py2exe

When I run an EXE file which was created by py2exe, everything is running fine, but when I close the window, it gives the following error:

```
memory cannot be written
```

What is going wrong?  Whatever I do,the cue is still received. But when I run the `.py` file directly, everything is running ok.

Comment: By the way, my systerm is win xp.

Comment: When I change to other computers with win XP,,the issue is still .Now I change to Win10 ,the issue will not appeared. How can I resolve the problem in my computer win Win xp?